# dynamic data - all option in paging

Tags: asp.net, dynamic-data

I'm developing a dynamic data web app. On list.aspx page it has GridViewPager control for paging, it option in drop down list as 10,20,.. rows in a page like that, but it does not an option show all rows in a page.
How I can add "All" option in it?

Comment: Your question is not so clear. Please provide more info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In content folder Dynamic Data site lies the code for GridViewPager control.

What I have done is I added "All" option in dropdown list with values 0, and in the code behind file in function DropDownListPageSize_SelectedIndexChanged I check if selected value is 0 then set AllowPaging = false else true.

```
protected void DropDownListPageSize_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (_gridView == null)
        {
            return;
        }
        DropDownList dropdownlistpagersize = (DropDownList)sender;
        int sz=Convert.ToInt32(dropdownlistpagersize.SelectedValue);
        //_gridView.PageSize = Convert.ToInt32(dropdownlistpagersize.SelectedValue);
        if (sz<=0)
        {
            _gridView.AllowPaging = false;
            //_gridView.DataBind();
            //return;
        }
        else
        {
            _gridView.AllowPaging = true;
            _gridView.PageSize = sz;
            _gridView.AllowPaging = true;
        }
        int pageindex = _gridView.PageIndex;
        _gridView.DataBind();
        if (_gridView.PageIndex != pageindex)
        {
            //if page index changed it means the previous page was not valid and was adjusted. Rebind to fill control with adjusted page
            _gridView.DataBind();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

I assume you are referring to a GridView and the automatic paging functionality included. If not please clarify. However, if this is the case then the default paging options do not include a show all. You can roll your own, I would start here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5aw1xfh3.asp

Answer (score 0):

You will have to implement your own pager and attached it to the Gridview. Default pager will not give you this option. May be this link could help you. http://www.codeproject.com/KB/grid/GridView_pager.aspx